# Transact-SQL to sum up elapsed time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my database the records start and stop times for a specific task.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
Start                       Stop
9/15/2008 5:59:46 PM        9/15/2008 6:26:28 PM
9/15/2008 6:30:45 PM        9/15/2008 6:40:49 PM
9/16/2008 8:30:45 PM        9/15/2008 9:20:29 PM
9/16/2008 12:30:45 PM       12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM
```

I would like to write a script that totals up the elapsed minutes for these time frames, and wherever there is a 12/31/9999 date, I want it to use the current date and time, as this is still in progress.

How would I do this using Transact-SQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM( CASE  WHEN Stop = '31 dec 9999' 
                   THEN DateDiff(mi, Start, Stop)
                   ELSE DateDiff(mi, Start, GetDate())
             END ) AS TotalMinutes 
FROM    task
```

However, a better solution would be to make the `Stop field nullable, and make it null when the task is still running.  That way, you could do this:`

```
SELECT  SUM( DateDiff( mi, Start, IsNull(Stop, GetDate() ) ) AS TotalMinutes 
FROM    task
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is cleaner:

```
   SELECT  SUM(
               DATEDIFF(mi, Start, ISNULL(NULLIF(Stop,'99991231'), GetDate()))
              ) AS ElapsedTime
   FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Select Sum(
    DateDiff(
        Minute,
        IsNull((Select Start where Start != '9999.12.31'), GetDate()),
        IsNull((Select End where End != '9999.12.31'), GetDate())
    )
)
from *tableName*
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work for SQL Server, other databases use different functions for date calculation and getting the current time.

```
Select  Case When (Stop <> '31 Dec 9999') Then 
          DateDiff(mi, Start, Stop) 
        Else 
          DateDiff(mi, Start, GetDate()) 
        End
From    ATable
```

Answer (score 0):

The [datediff function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) can display the elapsed minutes. The if statement for the 12/31/9999 check I'll leave as an excercise for the reader ;-)

Answer (score 0):

--you can play with the datediff using mi for minutes

-- this give you second of each task

```
select  Start,  
        Stop, 
        CASE 
            WHEN Stop = '9999-12-31' THEN  datediff(ss, start,getdate())
            ELSE datediff(ss, start,stop) 
        END duration_in_seconds 

from mytable
```

-- sum

```
Select Sum(duration_in_seconds)
from 
(
select  Start,  
        Stop, 
        CASE 
            WHEN Stop = '9999-12-31' THEN  datediff(ss, start,getdate())
            ELSE datediff(ss, start,stop) 
        END duration_in_seconds 

from mytable)x
```

Answer (score 0):

Datediff becomes more difficult to use as you have more dateparts in your difference (i.e. in your case, looks like minutes and seconds; occasionally hours).  Fortunately, in most variations of TSQL, you can simply perform math on the dates.  Assuming this is a date field, you can probably just query:

select duration = stop - start

For a practical example, let's select the difference between two datetimes without bothering with a table:

select convert(datetime,'2008-09-17 04:56:45.030') - convert(datetime,'2008-09-17 04:53:05.920')

which returns "1900-01-01 00:03:39.110", indicating there are zero years/months/days; 3 mins, 39.11 seconds between these two datetimes.  From there, your code can TimeSpan.Parse this value.

Answer (score 0):

Using help from AJ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81905/transact-sql-to-sum-up-elapsed-time#83005), BelowNinety's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81905/transact-sql-to-sum-up-elapsed-time#82039) and Nerdfest's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81905/transact-sql-to-sum-up-elapsed-time#82039), I came up with the following:

```
Select Sum(
    Case When End = '12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM' Then
         DateDiff(mi, Start, Getdate()) 
    Else 
         DateDiff(mi, Start, End) 
    End) As ElapsedTime 
From Table
```

Thanks for the help!